# Error receiving Regarding JQuery Sortable Serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get id values with JQuery. But, I am facing a problem.
The codes I wrote are:

```
 $('.table').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var id = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        console.log(id);
    }
});
```

When I write and run these codes, I get an error message when I need to write id in the console section.

The error I got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function
at HTMLTableSectionElement.update...
```

continues as.

Please can you help me?

Comment: Can you provide HTML and JS code? Need to check what you are exactly importing

Comment: I don't know if there is a problem with HTML and JS codes. Multiple javascript files are called in the footer section and some css files and JQuery library are called in the header section.

In fact, it is very strange that I get such an error in this file while performing sortable operations related to JQuery in other files.